Why skipping semicolon before using Array method breaks code?
If I use an Array method directly on any Array after a line that's missing a semicolon:
let foobar = 0
[0, 1, 2].some(foo => !!foo) // throws an error

it will throw an error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'some')
Strangely, the error persists even after transcompiling the code with esbuild, or Babel.
It doesn't happen if I add the missing semicolon, or use the Array method on a variable of Array type:
let foobar = 0;
[0, 1, 2].some(foo => !!foo) // works

let foobar = 0
const someArray = [0, 1, 2]
someArray.some(foo => !!foo) // also works

Why is that?

This is why it makes sense to have a formatter, such as prettier, enabled catch issues like this ;) https://prettier.io/docs/en/options#semicolons
